# Advantage Database Server 8.1 UNIQUE CONSTRAINT multiple columns

Tags: alter-table, advantage-database-server

I am working on an Advantage Database Server 8.1 and I have created a new table. I want to add a unique constraint for the combination of 2 columns.
I tried

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName 
UNIQUE (ColumnName1, ColumnName2)
```

but I get the error 
"ERROR IN SCRIPT: poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2115;  [Extended Systems][Advantage SQL Engine]Expected lexical element not found:  You are missing the column names. -- Location of error in the SQL 
statement is: 33 (line: 2 column: 5)"

Comment: The proper syntax for a column constraint is `ALTER TABLE TableName   ALTER COLUMN ColumnName ADD CONSTRAINT Whatever`. As you've correctly determined, what you want is not a column constraint but a unique index instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the solution I found is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ConstraintName ON TableName (ColumnName1, ColumnName2);
```